# If statement body does not execute

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this code with this `if` statement. To me it looks like it's programmed right, but the `if` statement's code never executes. I know my variables are set to `true`, but it doesn't work.

Here is the Update function with the if:

```
void Update()
{   
    if (t0 && t2)
    {
        Debug.Log("Bingo");
        Application.LoadLevel("Bingo");
    }
}
```

Here's the code that sets the variables to true:

```
if(gameObject.name.Equals("Button 0"))
{
    t0 = true;
    Debug.Log(gameObject.name);
}

if (gameObject.name.Equals("Button 2"))
{
    t2 = true;
    Debug.Log(gameObject.name);
}
```

I know that these variables are set to `true`, though it's strange, because if I set the variabes `true` from somewhere else in the code, it works.

Comment: I suspect that t0 and t2 are being set differently by the time it gets to your Update() method. did you place a breakpoint in your Update() method to see what the values are?

Comment: It very well could be a race condition. Are there other threads potentially updating t0 and/or t2?

Comment: @Ahmedilyas The Update function gets called every frame

Comment: What if you just add `Debug.Log(t0 + ", " +  t2)` in `Update` outside of the `if` statement-- are they in fact both `true`?

Comment: what if you simply put a breakpoint on the line in question and debugged your code?????

Comment: How could `t0 && t2` ever be true?  The object's name can't be two different things at the same time.

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions, the tag [tag:unity] explicitly says "DO NOT USE ON QUESTIONS ABOUT THE UNITY GAME ENGINE (use: [tag:unity3d] instead) "

Comment: How about you show us what `t0 && t2` look like this is very poor in regards to asking a question and stating what looks right.. are you familiar with how to use the debugger and setting breakpoints.. what is the `typeof t0 and t2`

Comment: @sab669 Thanks a lot it worked!!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two if statements will only provide one true as the 'gameObject.name' value will only ever Equal either 'Button 0' Or 'Button 2' unless they are run at least twice meeting both 'Button 0' and 'Button 2' condition you will only have one true value

Answer (score 2):

Both if statement wont be true in single execution as button name cant hold two different values.

Use || instead of &&

```
void Update() { if (t0 || t2) { Debug.Log("Bingo"); Application.LoadLevel("Bingo"); } }
```